# mysql_result conversion to sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm just starting to learn PHP and I'm having difficulty converting mysql_result to something that uses sqlsrv.

The code I'm trying to convert is:
(edited to include the full code)

```
 function database($querydb) {

global $global;
global $field;

if (isset($global['queries'])) {
    $global['queries']++;
} else {
    $global['queries'] = "1";
}
$field['queries'] = $global['queries'];
if (isset($global['query_log'])) {
    $global['query_log'] .= "\n<br>$querydb";
} else {
    $global['query_log'] = "$querydb";
}

$serverName = "XXX";
$uid = "XXX";
$pwd = "XXX";
$dbName = "XXX";


$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $dbName, "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $querydb) or return_error("Query Error: $querydb");

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
        {
        $global['dbresult'] = $row;
        }


if ((substr($querydb,0,6)!="INSERT") && (substr($querydb,0,6)!="UPDATE") && (substr($querydb,0,6)!="DELETE")) {

while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
$global['dbnumber'] = mysql_numrows($global['dbresult']);  // original $dbnumber
}

return;

}

function return_error($error) {
print $error;
exit;
}

function date_status($date, $username) {

global $global;
global $field;
global $input;
global $text;

$status = "0";

if ($username!="") {

    $query = "SELECT countedrow.total, id, start_date, end_date FROM calendar JOIN (SELECT total = COUNT(*) FROM oc_calendar) AS countedrow ON 1=1";

    database($query);


    for ($i = 0; $i < $global['dbnumber']; $i++) {

        $status = "1";

        $event_id = sqlsrv_fetch_array($global['dbresult'],$i,"id"); 


    }
}

return $status;

}
```

I have tried sqlsrv_get_field, sqlsrv_fetch, sqlsrv_fetch_array but I'm obviously not getting the syntax right and missunderstanding this as I'm getting an error of:

> sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in...

... with what ever I do.

How do I extract the id from the array to set $event_id ? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this your real code? According to the manual, `sqlsrv_query()` *Returns a statement resource on success and `FALSE` if an error occurred.* It cannot return an array. :-?

Comment: Returns an array on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.

Comment: Returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error occurred. - from php.net

Comment: @DevZer0 yeah i was looking at the fetch array function not the query function

Comment: Please, this code, to me, looks like you're still learning PHP+MySQL. If so, _don't learn about `mysql_*`_, as it's a deprecated extension. Learn about `PDO` and `mysqli_*` and prepared statements

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - This is a SQL Server question. The OP is just (apparently) migrating an old MySQL site.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: noticed after posting comment, but some people still don't know about the deprecation of `mysql_*`, so I'm leaving the comment as is.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario - it was a cut town version to (badly) illustrate what I was trying to do.  The original question has now been edited to include the whole lot (and where I am now up to)

Answer (score 0):

```
$querydb = "SELECT countedrow.total, id, start_date, end_date FROM oc_calendar JOIN (SELECT total = COUNT(*) FROM oc_calendar) AS countedrow ON 1=1";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $querydb);

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $event_id = $row["id"];
}
```

Does this work?

Why on earth were you mapping all the rows individually in a while to a globalvar and then looping the global var again! just loop it all directly if you need to return it out of a function back global then pass it as a return array NOT a global

Comment: No Joy I'm afraid..

I have edited the original question so that it included all the code rather than just a (badly) illustrated version.

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't know how to provide a valid first argument for `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` but your code already does it right:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $querydb) or return_error("Query Error: $querydb");
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
}
```

But then you get lost in your own spaghetti:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
{
    $global['dbresult'] = $row;
}
$event_id = sqlsrv_fetch_array($global['dbresult'],$i,"id");
```

I honestly suggest that you drop this code and start from scratch.

Comment: Its the spaghetti part that I'm lost in!

    for ($i = 0; $i < $global['dbnumber']; $i++) {

      $status = "1";

      $event_id = mysql_result($global['dbresult'],$i,"id");
   }

Comment: If you want to learn, you have excellent (and simple) usage examples in the manual. Porting that mess from MySQL to SQL Server (where database calls are the least problem) will be slower than writing it from scratch. If it's just an assignment to have to do, well, good luck :)